# Placing perpendicular labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, style

I'm trying to obtain the same label style than **Perpendicular Placement Orientation** from ArcGIS in QGIS. As QGIS doesn't have this feature as default, the option would be using custom placement for this.

An ArcGIS example:

[image]

### A workaround in QGIS

#### Settings:

Data defined coordinate X (label in the middle of he line):

```
$x_at( num_points( $geometry)/2)
```

Data defined coordinate Y (same as X's location):

```
$y_at( num_points( $geometry)/2)
```

Data defined Rotation:

```
angle_at_vertex( $geometry , num_points( $geometry)/2)
```

[image]

For only for 2/3 labels, the placement is acceptable. For lines with a lot of breaks with different angles, it's more difficult to obtain a nice label.

ArcGIS seems to search the line segment with fewer breaks or a straight segment. Is there a way to obtain coordinates or geometry of the straightest line segment using *Expression builder* for a better label placement?

Comment: how about taking an average of the angles at several vertices

Comment: @csk I've tried with `line_interpolate_angle($geometry, some lenght)` and taking several `angle_at_vertex( $geometry , num_points( $geometry))`. A loop over this function could be an aproach, but I can't do it directly in Expresion builder

Comment: it seems you want to find a section of the line where the angle at each vertex is approximately equal to the line_interpolate_angle

Comment: @csk yes, something like that. A straight line segment to place labels

Answer (score 2):

### Actual workaround

Suppose this kind of geometries:

[image]

I tried to find a good placement. I'm working with atlas also, so I used a 3% distance of atlas feature from the mid part of the interpolation line per feature's vertices to place labels:

Something like this:

[image]

And I create an arrow from the feature's middle vertex to the label:

[image]

---

### Settings:

#### Arrow:

*Geometry generator*

```
make_line(make_point($x_at( num_points( $geometry)/2) , $y_at( num_points( $geometry)/2)),
  project( line_interpolate_point(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),$y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))),
  length(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),$y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))))/2),length(@atlas_geometry)*0.03,
   (radians(line_interpolate_angle(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),$y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))),
  0.0001)))+ pi() *0.5))
```

#### Label

*Data define X*

```
x(project( line_interpolate_point(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),
  $y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))),
  length(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),$y_at(1)),
  make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))))/2),length(@atlas_geometry)*0.03,
   (radians(line_interpolate_angle(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),
  $y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))),0.0001)))+ pi() *0.5))
```

*Data define Y*

```
y(project( line_interpolate_point(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),
  $y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))),
  length(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),$y_at(1)),
  make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))))/2),length(@atlas_geometry)*0.03,
   (radians(line_interpolate_angle(make_line(make_point($x_at(1),
  $y_at(1)),make_point($x_at(-1),$y_at(-1))),0.0001)))+ pi() *0.5))
```

Maybe this could be helpful for someone.

If there is a better approach, glad to receive it.